# Return object with 2 optional ctors in function

Tags: c++, function, object, constructor, return

I have function in c++ with 2 optional c'tor of an object I've built (one with something in vector "vals" and other without).

```
...
    RecievedMessage a(sc, type);
    if (!vals.empty()){
        //a.~RecievedMessage();
        RecievedMessage a(sc, type, vals);
    }
    return &a;
}
```

the line in // is optional.

Would it work (with or without the optional line)? Why? If no, how to fix it without setter for "vals"?
thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot return pointer to a local object

Comment: This is in no way a situation where explicitly calling a destructor is warranted.

Comment: The `a` in the `if` branch has no relation to the `a` in the outer branch. It does not replace it or overwrite it. It simply *hides* it for the remainder of the scope (the `if` branch).

Comment: than there isn't a problem in the code(without the D'tor)? @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: Your code does not make any sense, other than that there is no problem. What type does this function return?

Comment: `auto a = vals.empty() ? ReceivedMessage(sc, type) : ReceivedMessage(sc, type, vals);` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 yea and then return address of `a`

Comment: "`a.~RecievedMessage();`" - the only situation I can think of where it can make sense to explicitly call a destructor is when managing objects in some memory pool via placement new and similar. Calling the destructor of an object more than once is undefined behaviour and if *you* call it explicitly and the compiler then calls it again when it goes out of scope, then *bam*; one way ticket to UB land.

Comment: `return &a;` would return address of local variable -> dangling pointer. (Or maybe you overload `operator &`...)

Comment: @arik *Strictly speaking*, you might say there isn't a problem with the code, except it certainly doesn't do what you expect it to do and dereferencing it's result would be undefined behavior. I would say that while I can't definitively say it's wrong from the limited information you've provided, it's hard to imagine a scenario where this will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is all over the place, but what I think you're looking for is something like this:

```
ReceivedMessage *MakeReceivedMessage (foo sc, bar type, vector<whatever>& vals)
{
    if (vals.empty())
        return new ReceivedMessage (sc, type);

    return new ReceivedMessage (sc, type, vals);
}
```

Of course, it would be better in this example to just have a single constructor and have the object test whether `vals` is empty when appropriate, but, in general, you can call whatever constructor you like whenever you like.  Just manage your object lifetimes properly (and don't - ever - return a pointer to an object on the stack).

Example usage (to manage the lifetime of the object returned properly):

```
std::unique_ptr<ReceivedMessage> MyReceivedMessage (MakeReceivedMessage (...));
MyReceivedMessage->DoFunkyStuffWithMessage ();
....
```

Or, as melpomene  points out, you can return a `std::unique_ptr<ReceivedMessage>` in the first place.  Some (many?) would prefer that.  You can construct it with [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

Comment: Returning raw pointers is generally not recommended (because of confusion about object ownership). I think the current best practice is to return a `std::unique_ptr<ReceivedMessage>`.

Comment: @melpomene Sure, but the OP was confused enough as it was, I didn't want to throw too much in.  And that's probably slightly more expensive than doing `std::unique_ptr<ReceivedMessage> x (MakeReceivedMessage (...));` with the code as-is.  Depends on personal preference, I guess.  I'll edit the post with an example.

Comment: @melpomene Thought about this some more.  I prefer returning a raw pointer as the caller might want to stash it in a `std::shared_ptr`, and not necessarily in a `std::unique_ptr`.  It's **always** possible to screw up memory management in C++, too much hand-holding just makes it worse.

Answer (score 3):

No, it wouldn't work.

```
    RecievedMessage a(sc, type);
// Here we construct 'a'
    if (!vals.empty()){
        //a.~RecievedMessage();
// If we enable this line, we destroy 'a'
        RecievedMessage a(sc, type, vals);
// Here we construct a second 'a' that only exists in this block
    }
// End of block: The inner 'a' is destroyed here automatically
    return &a;
}
// End of block: The outer 'a' is destroyed here, again.
```

Destroying an object twice has undefined behavior. You don't want that.

If you don't call the destructor manually, the outer `a` is only destroyed once, which is good.

But in either case, `RecievedMessage a(sc, type, vals);` has nothing to do with the outer `a` and merely creates another variable.

There would be ways to work around that, but the final line of your code makes it all pointless:

```
    return &a;
```

You're returning the address of a local variable. This is broken in and of itself: When the function returns, all of its local variables are destroyed automatically, so what you're returning is an invalid pointer.

Comment: Maybe OP overloads `operator &`... ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Given the confusion with scoping/shadowing I find that unlikely. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are three main issues with your code right now:

First of all, your commented out call to the destructor `~ReceivedMessage()` should not be there at all.  In C++, the destructor of objects is automatically called when an object's lifetime ends (either when it goes out of scope, or when `delete` is called if it was dynamically allocated with `new`).  While there are some situations where explicitly calling a destructor is necessary ("placement new" for example), these are situations you're very unlikely to come across.

Secondly, your `RecievedMessage a(sc, type, vals);` declaration in the inner `if` does not replace the value of `a` in the outer scope.  This just creates another variable of the same name which shadows the outer `a`, while `return &a;` in the outer scope can only refer to the outer `a`.  The inner `a` no longer exists at this point as it has gone out of scope.

A way to fix this issue is to instead assign a new value to `a` by using the `=` operator and constructing a temporary `ReceivedMessage`:

```
if (!vals.empty()) {
    a = ReceivedMessage(sc, type, vals);
}
```

This should work as long as a correct `operator=` is defined (implicitly or otherwise) for `ReceivedMessage`.

Thirdly, your function is returning a pointer to the local variable `a`.  Since objects in C++ are destroyed as soon as they go out of scope, `a` no longer exists by the time the function has returned, so the `ReceivedMessage *` pointer the calling code obtains is invalid and it would be undefined behaviour to dereference that pointer and make use of it.

There are a couple of fixes to this issue:

The first option is instead of returning a pointer (`ReceivedMessage *`), just return a `ReceivedMessage` by value.

```
ReceivedMessage foo()
{
    ReceivedMessage a(123);

    return a;
}
```

This should work as long as a correct copy or move constructor is defined (implicitly or otherwise) for `ReceivedMessage`.

The second option is to make use of `std::unique_ptr`, and make your function instead return `std::unique_ptr<ReceivedMessage>`.

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<ReceivedMessage> foo()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ReceivedMessage> a;

    if (vals.empty()) {
        a = std::make_unique<ReceivedMessage>(sc, type);
    } else {
        a = std::make_unique<ReceivedMessage>(sc, type, vals);
    }

    return a;
}
```

The advantage to this approach is that `unique_ptr` is nullable, so you can create a null `unique_ptr` without having to construct a `ReceivedMessage` straight away.  Additionally, you can move and assign `unique_ptr` values safely without having a correct `operator=` or a correct copy / move constructor defined.

The calling code may look like this, when using `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<ReceivedMessage> message = foo();
foo->bar();
```

as opposed to the following when using `ReceivedMessage` directly:

```
ReceivedMessage message = foo();
foo.bar();
```